# how to dynamic update QComboBox in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

for example,the first combo box with option 1 to 10 ,the other combo box also is 1 to 10 , and when i select 2 in the first,i need the second combo box shows option 3 to 10 , i mean the second combo box's value should bigger than first.so how should i to in the PyQt5?

Answer (score 2):

You have to first initialize the combobox in `__init__` method

```
def __init__(self):
    #Write your __init__ body here
    self.comboBox1 = QComboBox()
    self.comboBox2 = QComboBox()
```

Then you can set the item of first combobox 1 - 10

```
for i in range(1,11):
    self.comboBox1.addItem(str(i))
```

You can use `currentTextChanged` signal to update comboBox2

```
self.comboBox1.currentTextChanged.connect(self.updateComboBox2)
```

`currentTextChanged` signal passes the new selected text value to method

So `updateComboBox2` method

```
def updateComboBox2(self, newValue):
     ''' New Value is the changed value of comboBox1
         Do whatever you want to do with it here
         for eg. '''
     if newValue == 2:
         self.comboBox2.clear()        #This will remove all previous items
         for j in range(3,11):
              self.comboBox2.addItem(str(j))
```

Comment: Why do you assume that the asker has not used `__init__`?

Comment: I just clarified that it should be initialised in init otherwise it won't work. I didn't assumed that asker has not used `__init__`

Comment: You must publish when you have written your answer completely because you might think that you are responding to something else. Your initial answer is not directly relevant to the question why I gave my downvote since it was a bad answer, your current (complete) answer is much better.

Comment: Ya I was using tabs to indent properly and by mistake it got post. Sorry for that.

Comment: On the other hand going to your answer I recommend calling clear () before adding the new elements because for example if in the combobox first there are numbers from 1 to 5, and in a first select flames to 4 then in the second combobox will be the 5, if in the second selection you select item 2 with your answer you would get items 2,3,4,5 and 5 in the second combobox, as you can see there are duplicate items.